# Drupal variable messages empty on frontpage

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-views

I've a drupal site with some plugins, everything is running fine, but i don't know why, in my frontpage this code isn't working:

```
if($is_front){  
   if ($messages):  
      print $messages;  
   endif;  
}
```

If i try to do a var_dump of messages, it results in empty string.
The same code, on other pages (not front) is working.
This variable is used when showing sys/drupal messages (ex: after user registration), if i set the user registration to show a page different than the frontpage, the message is showed, otherwise it's not.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously know that $messages is only populated when you submit a form and validation fails or something similar. I wonder if perhaps, that variable is being cleared upon redirection to the homepage and thus not showing up???

I assume you have a form or something on the homepage which you are submitting?

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Yes, thanks Alex, i'm on the registration page or password recovery, i'm not sure if there's any code redirecting it, from my side it seems as it directly goes to the frontpage and the variable is empty.